# Can I make a cluster of 3 tables a, b, and c if the shared columns are between (a and b) and (b and c)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I imagine something like this:

```
CREATE CLUSTER CLUSTER1
(table_a_PK number (2)), (table_b_PK nmber (2));

create index idx_table_a_PK on cluster1;
create index idx_table_b_PK on cluster1;

CREATE TABLE table_a
table_a_PK number (2) PRIMARY KEY,
other_row varchar(20)
CLUSTER cluster1;

CREATE TABLE table_b
table_b_PK number (2) PRIMARY KEY,
rowB number (2),
other_row2 varchar(20),

CONSTRAINT FK_rowB FOREIGN KEY (rowB) REFERENCES table_a (table_a_PK),
CLUSTER cluster1;

CREATE TABLE table_c
tabe_c_PK number (2) PRIMARY KEY,
rowC number (2),
other_row3 varchar(20),

CONSTRAINT FK_rowC FOREIGN KEY (rowC) REFERENCES table_b (table_b_PK),
CLUSTER cluster1;
```

I would like to be able to query 5 different tables. And they only share columns between 2 tables. Like, 1 and 2 share a column, 2 and 3 share a column, 3 and 4 share a column, and so on. I'd like to take advantage of clustering, so i'm trying to figure out how people do this in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

A table cluster is a group of tables that share common columns and store related data in the same blocks. When tables are clustered, a single data block can contain rows from multiple tables.

**The cluster key is the column or columns that the clustered tables have in common**. You specify the cluster key when creating the table cluster and when creating every table added to the table cluster.

The cluster key value is the value of the cluster key columns for a particular set of rows. All data that contains the same cluster key value is physically stored together. Each cluster key value is stored only once in the cluster and the cluster index, no matter how many rows of different tables contain the value.

A good cluster key has enough unique values so that the group of rows corresponding to each key value fills approximately one data block. Having too few rows for each cluster key value can waste space and result in negligible performance gains. Cluster keys that are so specific that only a few rows share a common value can cause wasted space in blocks, unless a small SIZE was specified at cluster creation time.

In your case, I don't see any benefit in using clusters, besides you don't share a common column between all the tables.

[https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/tablecls.htm#CNCPT-GUID-CC31365B-83B0-4E09-A047-BF1B79AC887A](http://Cluster%20Tables)

Comment: So are you saying that all the tables need to share a column and what i'm attempting is impossible?

Comment: I never tried that, but it does not make any sense. Clusters are useful when all elements are shared by a common key, which is not your case. Also you must be very careful because they are for very specific situations. In your case, you don't need them at all, you are not going to gain any performance, even if you put the same column in all the tables.

Comment: @ellie-lumen, if you consider, upvote the answer. really appreciated